# the nest for loop array variable in MATLAB parfor error cannot be classified

Tags: arrays, matlab, parfor

I use the PSO algorithm to find the global best positions. The Matlab code that I would like to run in parallel looks like the following:

```
%% Particle loop   
parfor iter=1:ParticleNum
 for FoldNum = 1:10  
   .............
   FoldHL(FoldNum)=Hamming_loss(labelTestOut,TVT);  
 end
   HLoss(iter,:) = mean(FoldHL);
end
```

and the error information:

```
The variable FoldHL in a parfor cannot be classified.
```

Any idea why I am getting this error and how it can be resolved?

Comment: foldnum is the count of ten fold validation,FoldHL is the array of HammingLoss(a  criterion of multilabel classification)

Comment: Read here: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/223299-error-the-variable-in-a-parfor-cannot-be-classified